# How to have Jekyll blog posts not showing the date?

Tags: jekyll

I reedit my posts all the time and the dates don't mean anything so I want to remove them from the posts' titles (not from the titles of the markdown files).

Answer (score 6):

By title I take that you mean the url segments which contain the date + the post title. If so:

you can specify the permalink to Not contain the date on post basis (front matter) like so:

```
---
title: My new post
permalink: /:title/
---
```

or if you want this to apply to posts, use it in _config.yml:

```
permalink: /:title/
```

There are also other predefined permalinks [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), and their components (slugs) can be used in the customization above.

Comment: No, by title I meant the title of the posts when they show up in the blog, not their urls.

Comment: do you mean the blog index or the single post page ?

Comment: Okay, for the post page, remove  `{{ page.date }}` where you find it in your the post layout file (depending in which theme you use; e.g.: _layouts -> post.html).

Comment: The same goes for the index. check any presence of date an remove it. (e.g. `<span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

In the _config.yml file remove the the `show_date=true`
For example:

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: posts
    values:
      layout: posts 
      author_profile: false
      read_time: true
      #show_date: true
      comments: true
      share: true
      related: true
```